# Crear llaves escriptadas

Tags: php

No se si esta bien la pregunta que hago, pero estoy tratando de crear llaves de seguridad encriptadas y la mejor opción que encontré es `openssl_encrypt` e hice un ejemplo tomando el `id` del usuario para encriptarlo y desencriptarlo, pero lo que quiero saber es si es una buena opción o no, porque también iba a usar `password_hash` pero necesito desencriptar para tomar ese valor para generar pagos posteriormente.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php

define('KEY', 'llavetres');
define('COD', 'AES-128-ECB');

//$usarid = <?=$row['uid'];?>
$userid = 46;

echo openssl_encrypt($userid,COD,KEY).'<br>'; //llave VyUzxz+X/Kjzflm7bs4o/w==

$llave = 'VyUzxz+X/Kjzflm7bs4o/w==';

echo openssl_decrypt($llave,COD,KEY); //obtengo 46

?>
```

Gracias!

Comment: Cual es el error con tu código?

Comment: Me interesa. Yo uso md5 y jamas busque otra alternativa. Openssl para mi esta bien y por lo que veo poder desencriptarlo es muy favorable porque con md5 no se puede desencriptar.

Comment: @AntoniaHerrera me paso eso con md5 y lo que tiene de bueno `password_hash` es que con un solo dato se crean varios códigos, te lo recomiendo. Pero el cambio a `openssl` es para llevar el id del usuario a procesar pagos.

Comment: @STN te dejo mi [facebook](https://www.facebook.com/anto.herrera.33483) y si quieres puedes escribirme allí.

Comment: Dale te escribo. Gracias!

Comment: Tu pregunta se basa en opiniones. Tu duda: *quiero saber es si es una buena opción o no*, no tiene una respuesta única. Puede que si, puede que no. Todo dependerá de tu caso de uso. En cuanto a confundir *hash* con *encriptado* ya la cosa es diferente, ya que son precisamente cosas distintas. El proceso de encriptado es un proceso bidireccional, en cambio el proceso de *hash* es unidireccional, he allí la mayor diferencia. Saludos

Comment: Gracias Mauricio. Es por eso que no sabia si hacer esta pregunta en este medio. Comparto que no es una respuesta única, pero a veces en muchos aspectos, hay programadores con mucha mas experiencia para orienta mejor por donde uno puede seguir. Siempre tomamos a alguien como referente para llegar a un punto, es por eso que existe el maestro, a pesar de las distintas opiniones. Y en este punto, lo bueno que tiene programar es que se puede llagar a tener un resultado de varias maneras. Como yo, hay muchos que tienen dudas que aunque parezcan simples, necesitamos alguien que nos oriente. Gracias!

Comment: @STN eso pasa con los autodidactas y es verdad lo que tú dices y no quiero hacer preguntas así porque voy a parecer tonta y después me ponen puntos negativos. Y en mi caso también me pasa que soy autodidacta y veo muchos videos y son muy pocos los que me ayudan y google no tiene todas las respuestas. Respecto a encriptar, no es un tema menor y tú duda también ayuda a otros y otras como yo.

Comment: Hola @AntoniaHerrera **No es buena práctica** permitir desencriptar las contraseñas porque **pueden caer en manos de atacantes** y se crea un **agujero de seguridad potencial**. Y, aunque nada es 100% seguro, el paso contraseña + tokendeseguridad -> función resumen encriptada (sin retorno) -> validación hace que los ataques mediante contraseñas sean difíciles. (se necesita fuerza bruta y posibilidades de intentos recursivos, o mecanismos de criptoanálisis) hecho que brinda mayor seguridad (aúnque **nunca será completa**).